# redirecting issue with .htaccess file in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site like https://yoursitename.com. I am using `.htaccess` file for redirection. The code in `.htaccess` file is as :

```
RewriteRule ^websites/all /filter.php?module=1&filter=all [R=301,NC,P]
```

But redirection goes me to another page which has the following htaccess code :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-detail.php?c=$1
```

What I am doing wrong?

Content of `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /

RewriteRule ^websites/all /filter.php?module=1&filter=all [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/established /filter.php?module=1&filter=established [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/starter /filter.php?module=1&filter=starter [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/active /filter.php?module=1&filter=active [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/ending /filter.php?module=1&filter=ending [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/justsold /filter.php?module=1&filter=justsold [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/dealflow /filter.php?module=1&filter=dealflow [R=301,NC,P]

RewriteRule ^domains/all /filter.php?module=2&filter=all [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/auction /filter.php?module=2&filter=auction [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/active /filter.php?module=2&filter=active [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/ending /filter.php?module=2&filter=ending [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/justsold /filter.php?module=2&filter=justsold [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/appraisal /filter.php?module=2&filter=appraisal [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^domains/brokered /filter.php?module=2&filter=brokered [R=301,NC,P]

RewriteRule ^apps/all /filter.php?module=3&filter=all [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^apps/ios /filter.php?module=3&filter=ios [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^apps/android /filter.php?module=3&filter=android [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^apps/active /filter.php?module=3&filter=active [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^apps/ending /filter.php?module=3&filter=ending [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^apps/justsold /filter.php?module=3&filter=justsold [R=301,NC,P]

RewriteRule ^(websites|domains|apps|digitalGoods|sell)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ ./show-digital.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-detail.php?c=$1


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hiwebby\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hiwebby\.com$

RewriteRule ^blog\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/hiwebby\.com\/blog\/index\.php\/Support\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are both rules in same .htaccess file? In which order? Can you show more relevant parts of the .htaccess file? And what is the url you try to visit?

Comment: Is there any other code in `.htaccess` file

Comment: @GolezTrol , yes both rules are in same htaccess file.

Comment: @lkdhruw, ys, .htaccess file has more rules.

RewriteRule ^websites/all/(.*)$ /filter.php?module=1&filter=all [R=301,NC,P,L]
RewriteRule ^websites/established/(.*)$ /filter.php?module=1&filter=established [R=301,NC,P,L]
RewriteRule ^websites/starter /filter.php?module=1&filter=starter [R=301,NC,P,L]
RewriteRule ^websites/active /filter.php?module=1&filter=active [R=301,NC,P,L]
RewriteRule ^websites/ending /filter.php?module=1&filter=ending [R=301,NC,P,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-detail.php?c=$1

same for module 2 and module 3

Comment: @Ankit It would be better if you add these lines to your question.

Comment: @lkdhruw i have added the complete .htaccess code and waiting for your reply...

Comment: I've fixed question tags *again*. This is not a PHP question and it **is** a mod_rewrite question.

Comment: @Ankit Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @lkdhruw i have checked your answer, it has solved my problem 99%. The main comment is within your answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [L] Flag (Last) - so no other rules are checked

```
RewriteRule ^websites/all /filter.php?module=1&filter=all [R=301,NC,P,L]
```

Comment: sorry sir, could not succeed....


 
the real url is yoursitename.com/filter.php?module=1&filter=all

the url should show like yoursitename.com/websites/all where module = 1(website) and filter = all

Comment: 1) Make sure you did not mess with RewriteBase in your htaccess
2) When testing 301 redirects use a command line tool, not the browser, browsers oftenly cache 301 redirects very aggressively (the are permanent) - i would suggest to test via curl or httpie

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules seem dubious at many lines. In my answer, there
are few questions for you as well. Configuring server behavior with rewrite rules is tricky any misconfiguration will lead to the serious problem with the websites. That's why the complete lookup is necessary. Also, you should consider reading the document https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#page-header

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

That's fine.

---

```
RewriteRule ^websites/all /filter.php?module=1&filter=all [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/established /filter.php?module=1&filter=established [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/starter /filter.php?module=1&filter=starter [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/active /filter.php?module=1&filter=active [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/ending /filter.php?module=1&filter=ending [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/justsold /filter.php?module=1&filter=justsold [R=301,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^websites/dealflow /filter.php?module=1&filter=dealflow [R=301,NC,P]
```

But in the code shown above:
Probably you are not using a proxy or redirect. So you can use flag `[NC,L]` instead. And in place of all the seven lines, you can use just

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^websites/(.*)$ filter.php?module=1&filter=$1 [NC,L]
```

Similarly

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^domains/(.*)$ filter.php?module=2&filter=$1 [NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ filter.php?module=3&filter=$1 [NC,L]
```

so on (if there is any).

---

```
RewriteRule ^(websites|domains|apps|digitalGoods|sell)($|/) - [L]
```

In your above line how you are going to handle requests like `domain.com/websites`. Is there any directory named `websites`?.

> The "-" syntax means that the requested URI is not modified.

---

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ ./show-digital.php?url=$1
```

In above code `.` is there for any purpose in `./show-digital.php?url=$1`? and also there is no flag provided. You can modify it like

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ show-digital.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-detail.php?c=$1 [NC,P]
```

Here also correct flag would be `[NC,L]`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-detail.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hiwebby\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hiwebby\.com$

RewriteRule ^blog\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/hiwebby\.com\/blog\/index\.php\/Support\/" [R=301,L]
```

**In this section can you explain what you want to do.**

Comment: thank you very much. As you asked, there are folders with name websites, domains and apps. But filter.php, show-detail.php and show-digital.php files are in the root.  Your provided code is working well. But there is one little problem. Redirection of domains and apps are working fine, but websites redirection is not taking me to required page. if i use domain.com/website, then it is working but not with domain.com/websites

Comment: If i want to access [link](domain.com/websites/index.php), it takes me to filter.php page but in address bar it shows the url domain.com/websites/

Comment: @Ankit So the `domain.com/websites/index.php` exists you can place rewrite condition before rewrite rule. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Now the problem has been 100% solved. Thanks again. Can we contact personally via mail?

Comment: Sure you can contact me at lkdhruw@live.com